# Django - images upload in wrong folder

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-media

Making some kind of blog website and can't make homepage to show article images...
Images should be uploaded to media/profile_pics , but it just makes profile_pics folder in app folder and uploads images there.

my models.py :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="YNTN")
    #author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pics", blank=True, null=True)
    #body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blog_posts")

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.title + " | " + str(self.author))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home")
```

my views.py:

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
```

my forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'body', 'image')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Title of the Blog'}),
            'title_tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Copy the title with no space and a hyphen in between'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Content of the Blog'}),
        }

my home.html
```

```
<div class="row">
    {% for post in object_list %}
    <div class="col-lg-4 my-4">
        <div class="card shadow" style="width: 20rem; height: 33rem;">
            <img src="/media/{{post.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." height="250px">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{post.title}} <br><small>by {{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}</small></h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{post.body|slice:":100"|safe}}</p>
              <a href={% url 'article-details' post.pk %} class="btn btn-primary">Read More {% if user.is_superuser %}<a href="delete_blog_post/{{post.slug}}/" class="btn btn-danger mx-4">Delete Blog</a>{% endif %}</a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

```

my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'yntn/yntnapp/media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Images should be in media/profile_pics, but instead, it is making profile_pics folder in my project folder and uploading images there...

Comment: As a side note: `<img src="/media/{{post.image}}"` and `<a href="delete_blog_post/{{post.slug}}/"` are both examples of bad approach and not a "django way". For the first one use `src="{{ post.image.url }}"` and for the second one use url reversion as you do here `{% url 'article-details' post.pk %}`

Comment: Please add to your question and example of full path where image is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set your MEDIA_ROOT like the following line.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Code-only answers, while they may indeed be correct solutions, are much more useful from a learning perspective when they are accompanied by an explanation. Please provide an explanation as to why this answer represents the solution.